# Need help understanding a Python snippet

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone help me understand why is the output of the following code snippet = None?

```
def func(x, y):

    """This is a function"""

    if x%3 == 0:

        return x

    elif x%3 == 1:

        return y

x = 1

y = 2

print(func(y=x, x=y))
```

Comment: Hint: What if neither of the `if` conditions is true? What will be returned? And why do you make it all the more confusing by swapping the meaning of `x` and `y` when setting the local variables with the same name?

Comment: this is actually from a python course that i am taking..

Comment: And the course is not explaining what it is supposed to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging -- stepping through the code and inspecting variables -- should make it all clear:

Just before the function is executed, the global variables `x` and `y` have already received their values:

```
x: 1
y: 2
```

Then the arguments are passed to the function. In this case they are passed by specifying their corresponding parameter names -- using `key = value` syntax: With `y=x` the *parameter* `y` (a local variable in the function's context) gets the value of the global variable `x`. And with `x=y` the parameter `x` gets the value of the global variable `y`. The order in which these arguments were passed is irrelevant, because they were passed as [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument), not as positional arguments.

When execution enters the function body, we have two local variables `x` and `y` and we can see they have these values:

```
Globals   Locals
x: 1      x: 2
y: 2      y: 1
```

The global variables are not accessible in this function, since they are shadowed by the local variables with the same names (but different values!)

The first `if` condition is false, because 2%3 is 2, not 0. The second `if` condition is also false as this expression is not 1 either. And so no `return` statement gets executed. Instead the function exits with the default return value, which is `None`, which is also the printed value.

Comment: Thanks! You have explained it better than the lecturer!